# mount: proc/: mount point does not exist

Tags: linux, mount, chroot

I recently messed up my Linux system.

So then I made an Arch Linux Live USB to **chroot** into my distro (parition: `/dev/nvme0n1p4`)

I typed the following commands:

1. `sudo mkdir /mnt/mydisc`
2. `sudo mount -o exec /dev/nvme0n1p4 /mnt/mydisc` and `cd /mnt/mydisc`
3. `sudo mount -t proc /proc proc/`
   with the following error: `mount: proc/: mount point does not exist`

I chrooted before on my laptop and everything was working perfectly with the same steps;
but now, I get this error.

Comment: well, `proc/` does not exist, so the error is fully on-point. And you'll want to mount `proc`, not `/proc`: `sudo mkdir proc; sudo mount -t proc proc proc/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The directories intended as mount points need to exist before they can be used:

```
sudo mkdir proc
```

Once that’s done, the “device” to mount is `proc`, not `/proc`:

```
sudo mount -t proc proc proc
```

or more explicitly,

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/mydisc/proc
sudo mount -t proc proc /mnt/mydisc/proc
```